# Workbench is not working - Application Error. For past 10 days

Tags: workbench, heroku

[image: Workbench Error Screenshot]We are getting this error and not able to work properly using workbench every time when it open when we do some action this error occcurs.,

Comment: What are you trying to do? There may be other ways to do so

Comment: Workbench is an open source project you can host your own version of workbench https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench, from here, or you can fork the branch and try to fix it as required for your self hosted workbench.

Comment: FWIW the Workbench issues are intermittent - opening a new session in a new private browser/incognito mode often resolves the issue. Recommended free alternative: [Visual Studio Code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code)